# JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,

Tags: java, maven, path, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using Pop!_OS (Ubuntu 22.04) and downloaded Java and Maven.

I added the Paths of the directories to the .bashrc file, cause i want to use maven via the bash console.

The .bashrc file is eddit as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6

export JAVA_HOME
export MAVEN_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Java and Maven Path

```
$JAVA_HOME -> bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
$MAVEN_HOME -> bash: /opt/apache-maven-3.8.6
```

ls -ld $JAVA_HOME shows:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-17-openjdk-amd64
```

ls $JAVA_HOME/bin/java shows:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

If I now call **mvn -version** via the bash console I get the following error message:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this
> environment variable is needed to run this program.

I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong, do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does `ls -ld $JAVA_HOME` show? Or `ls $JAVA_HOME/bin/java`? Also: there's a typo in your `PATH` definition where you use `$JAVE_HOME` (E instead of A).

Comment: @JoachimSauer fixed the typo.. and edit the question

Comment: Shouldn't maven be installed next to you're jdk?

Comment: @user16320675 no it does not work...  File or directory not found.. iam using the bash console in intellj Idea... in the normal Shell (Terminal) mvn -version works

Comment: *... and downloaded Java and Maven.* Even that somewhat strange distro should feature Java and Maven in its repos, so you should have installed them with ```sudo apt install``` . I would get rid of what you've got and do that first. Then start again with your env vars if you want them